# Get 2 meta values from key column (Single table)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

How can I select the **Display_Name** and **Play_Time** on MySQL query?

[image]

This is my current query but nothing displays:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE submission_id = '47' AND `key` = 'Display_Name' AND `key` = 'Play_Time'
```

display the value of display_name and play_time by calling those red highlighted keys on a screenshot.

Comment: Please do not post screen shots but provide data examples and preferably scripts that can be run on anyone's machine to help find/debug your code.

Comment: Fixed. I just need to use "OR" operator. My goodness, I didn't think about that!

Comment: If you're not accustomed to using `OR`, you should make sure you understand [operation precedence rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html). You might need to use parentheses to make it work the way you intend.

Comment: Alternatively, use the [IN() predicate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in).